# Openpyxl will create and save the workbook but will not open it

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I am using openyxl to load and save a workbook but I want it to open the file in Excel when it is done.  I am very new to programming and Python.  I am probably missing something very basic.  Using windows 10 and Anaconda.  I have tried these:

```
from openpyxl import Workbook 
from openpyxl import load_workbook 
wb = load_workbook(filename = 'book.xlsx') 
wb.save('sample_book.xlsx')
```

and

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
wb = load_workbook('book.xlsx') 
ws = wb.active 
# need to pull in data here
wb.save('sample_book.xlsx')
```

Both work they load and save the file to my hard drive but I want it to open in excel for review when the operation is complete.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Openpyxl works with `xlsx` files but it does not work with Excel. In fact, it runs on non-Windows platforms without any Excel support.

You can open an Excel file with Excel using `subprocess`. The simplest way would be:

```
subprocess.call([r'c:\path\to\excel.exe',  r'c:\path\to\sample_book.xlsx', shell=True])
```

This blocks your calling Python program until you close Excel.

This start Excel and your program keeps going:

```
subprocess.Popen([r'c:\path\to\excel.exe',  r'c:\path\to\sample_book.xlsx', shell=True])
```

Make sure to use `r''` for paths that have backslashes. `r''` makes a path string a raw string and escapes special charactrs such as `\n` or `\t`.

Comment: Thank you Mike!  I have been wanting to migrate the project to Mac anyway but being so new at this all I did not know if that would have an impact other than not owning a Mac version of the office suite.   I understand now.  Thank you again!

Comment: Great that it helped. BTW, you can [accept](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) an answer if it solves your problem.

Comment: Thanks Mike -accepted.  This was my first question!